# If $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=8xy $ for $ 0<x<y<1$, determine whether or not $X, Y$ are independent.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

$X$ and $Y$ are r.i.v

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=8xy $  for $ 0<x<y<1$

Determine whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$f_x=\int_x^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\text{d}y=\int_x^18xy\,\text{d}y=4x-4x^3$

$f_y=\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\text{d}x=\int_0^y 8xy\,\text{d}y=4y^3$

$f_{x,y}\neq f_x \cdot f_y \implies X,Y$ are independent.

Is my solution correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: The product is not the same so not independent. Solution is correct but the result is wrong(maybe a typo).